# Nexus 5 Unroot: Update Possibilities?

Tags: nexus-5

I somehow one-click rooted my Nexus 5 (without a computer) but want to unroot. If I go to Settings >>,About Device >> Update and install an update if there is one, will it delete root or get stuck on the boot logo because I'm root? I don't want to have issues but I also don't want root. Now I downloaded SuperSu and used the Temp Unroot option which basically just deletes root temporarily unless that option is DE-selected. So basically I don't have root now (I checked) but it's still there, I just want to know

1) Can I update without having problems? I have T-Mobile.

2) Is there an app that can just delete root for good, permanently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a solution.

Go to SuperSu >> Settings >> "Fully Unroot This Device." Done.

Answer (score 1):

To unroot the device all you have to flash the stock rom on your phone and lock the bootloader again. To do this you have to download the latest android 4.4.2 for Nexus 5 on your PC and Flash the same on your device with ADB commands. So before that you have to install the Android ADB and Fastboot drivers on your PC.

First Download the newest factory images to your PC And save the folder on your desktop.

[Download Link](https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images#hammerhead)

[Read the Full guide here with Step by Step Instruction](http://howtorootmobile.com/unroot-nexus-5-return-stock-factory-image/)

Comment: I already have stock, I didn't change ROMs.